MStest + Coverlet don't getting up to 100% coverage in cli, but I got 100% in codecov
I recently created a solution from scratch with a C# .NET 8.0 project.
The project is only about unit tests and isolated classes, which I intend to be a folder of algorithm exercises.
The project has mstest as test runner and coverlet as coverage collector.
I set properties on the project so that it generates coverage output in lcov.info format:
    <!-- Coverage -->
    <CollectCoverage>true</CollectCoverage>
    <CoverletOutputFormat>lcov</CoverletOutputFormat>
    <CoverletOutput>./lcov.info</CoverletOutput>
    <IncludeTestAssembly>true</IncludeTestAssembly>

The project only has just one class, with a single method with a single line.
Additionaly, has just one Test Class with a just single test method.
That lines is covered in test run, but in shell summary I got:
+----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| Module                     | Line   | Branch | Method |
+----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+
| algorithm-exercises-csharp | 88.88% | 100%   | 66.66% |
+----------------------------+--------+--------+--------+

+---------+--------+--------+--------+
|         | Line   | Branch | Method |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Total   | 88.88% | 100%   | 66.66% |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+
| Average | 88.88% | 100%   | 66.66% |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+

Then try to verify which part would not be covered.
With Coverage-gutters in Visual Studio Code, I was able to verify that all the code is covered.
Then take the output from lcov.info to codecov. Here the service tells me that I have 100% coverage.
Why is the result by cli different?
How can I increase coverage to 100% in CLI?
Command used (at .sln level):
dotnet test --verbosity normal

Runtime and SDK:
dotnet --version
8.0.204

Dependencies:
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.collector" Version="6.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="coverlet.msbuild" Version="6.0.2">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="17.9.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="3.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.3.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

IDE:
Visual Studio Code + C# Dev Kit
Repository:
https://github.com/sir-gon/algorithm-exercises-csharp

You appear to be generating coverage for a file at C:\Users\runneradmin\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.test.sdk\17.9.0\build\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk.Program.cs, which is uncovered. If you delete this file and run coverage again, does it show as 100%?

Thanks a lot! Based on your response @Drazisil I looked for the filename in the web and then I found this coverlet issue:
https://github.com/coverlet-coverage/coverlet/issues/604
I have solved the problem by adding the following property in test project:
<ExcludeByAttribute>TestSDKAutoGeneratedCode</ExcludeByAttribute>


Happy to help, @Gonzalo. Please mark this answer as the solution if this is resolved.
